# Can't mount network drive across subnets

Tags: windows, networking, nas, subnet, webdav

I seem to be having an issue when it comes to mapping a network drive to Windows' Explorer. I am trying to map my NAS which is located in 'Router1', and my computer which is in 'Router2', but every time I attempt to map it I get the error `Windows cannot access \\192.168.1.100\myshare`.
[image: Subnet Configuration]

In my case the scenario goes like this:

- Router 1:
- WAN: Static IP
- LAN: 192.168.0.1/24
- Router 2:
- WAN: 192.168.1.32
- LAN: 192.168.1.1/24

It also seems that both networks share the same SUBNET MASK

Comment: TP-Link Archer C9

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I tried your first solution, and it didn't work - I got the error `Error code: 4003
Subnet Mask doesn't match the Destination Network address, please enter again.`
I've also updated the question with some extra info in case that helps.

Comment: The IP address shown in "Advanced→Network→LAN" is 192.168.1.1, and sadly using the new data also gave me the same error. `Error code: 4003
Subnet Mask doesn't match the Destination Network address, please enter again.` - As for Router1's model and make, I don't really know, as it seems to be manufactured by the ISP. (Firmware version is: Vodafone-H-500-s-v3.4.13 - in case it helps). Here it was I see in router1 configuration. "Mobile, Port Mapping, DMZ, Parental Control, DNS & DDNS, UPnP, WoLAN"

Comment: So, when using the destination network as `192.168.0.0`, with the gateway as `192.168.0.32`, I got the error: `Error code: 4011
Destination Network address cannot be inside the subnet of WAN IP address, please enter again.` - And when using 0.0.0.0 as the gateway I got the error `
Error
Error code: 4004
Bad Gateway, please input another IP address.`

Comment: Im not to sure what you mean by setting the interface to “WAN”, although, yes, i tried what you said above, and got the error 4004.

Comment: I can't edit the System Routing Table, although in the System Routing List, I don't get the option to set LAN or WAN, and using the points mentioned above I still get the Error Code 4004

Comment: You know what, you probably simply need to setup the static routing or whatever on the `Router1` and tell it to send traffic on the other subnet over to `Router2` WAN IP address of `192.168.0.32` and not do anything at all with `Router2` static routing now that I think about it more. Otherwise when `Router1` tries to get to the subnet not in it's LAN scope it will send that back out its WAN to the Internet rather than `Router2` so look for similar functionality with static routes on `Router1` instead. Deleting other comments though to keep this cleaner.

Comment: So on router1 you somehow need to tell it for `192.168.1.0/24` to send that over to `192.168.0.32` so it sends it there rather than its `WAN`.

Comment: I looked into this some more and I think you may have a `SerComm H500-s` model Vodafone DSL router based on the detail I could find on the firmware version your provided. I see a lot Spanish on this over the web I cannot read and their [official Device Guides](https://support.vodafone.co.uk/Device-Guides) look horrible with no specific detail. If this document is accurate for your router; https://www.vodafone.co.nz/cms/documents/broadband-complete-manual.pdf then it looks like it just has no functionality to support forwarding a specific subnet to a LAN connected address `192.168.0.32`

Comment: And for what it is worth, I do not believe you ever tried sharing subnets for anything I advised or you said you did so I'm not sure what that is about. It looks like this Vodafone DSL router just doesn't support what you need perhaps and you are SOL or you may need to LAN to LAN for it to work and play with the more robust settings of Router2 if needed. I suppose it would not hurt to call Vodafone and ask them just in case though as they should be able to tell you right away if this is a router they suggested, leased, etc.

Answer (score 1):

First of all subnets do NOT share subnet masks. It's just similar in those networks.

It is unclear if you have NAT enabled on Router2. Please check it out. If NAT is enabled, everything should work fine and you should trace any possible issue somewhere else, e.g. if the NAS has proper default gateway.

If you like to have plain routing between the subnets, then proper route must be defined on Router1 or NAS for that to know where (by which IP address, here 192.168.0.32) to find 2nd LAN.

You can check that out with ping or trace from 2nd network:

```
ping 192.168.1.100
tracert 192.168.1.100
```

Comment: NAT is enabled in Router2, and using `tracert 192.168.0.100` I get the following result: `Tracing route to NAS [192.168.0.100]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1
  2     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  NAS [192.168.0.100]

Trace complete.`

Comment: your problem description for routers doesn't mach the picture. you need to connect from 192.168.2.x to \\192.168.1.100\myshare in LAN1. you cannot have a LAN of 192.168.0.x

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't say I follow, could you somehow clarify?

Comment: edited the post. you got these ranges 192.168.1.x and 192.168.2.x, there is no 192.168.0.x in the map. you want to access NAS under router1 to be accessible from LAN under router2. right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, although I should mention that router1 uses `192.168.0.x` and router2 uses '192.168.1.x'. I assume you got it from the image, although the image is just one I found online.